# Changing outcome column of a task in SharePoint 2007 through a workflow

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sharepoint, task

I am evaluating SharePoint 2007 for a document control system with workflows. So far, my experience has been "bitter" but I am not given any other option. The only tool I am able to use now is SharePoint Designer 2007. I have a few questions:

1. I noticed that there is a column called "Outcome" for every task which shows the same thing as "status" shows. If status is "Complete", outcome shows "Complete". I Googled it and it seems that outcome can be made to show "Accept/Reject" but I am unable to change the "outcome" column in SharePoint Designer 2007. In fact, I don't even see a field called Outcome. Whats the work around to this?
2. I am "remotely" developing this document management system. I figured that I cant use VS2008 to develop it since it needs to be running on the server machine itself and requires some DLL's from the Server itself (Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll or some such thing). I definitely wont get any access directly into the SharePoint server. Any other way to develop using VB or C# workflows for SharePoint 2007?
3. This question is a serious one. What is the architecture of SharePoint? Why is it so counter intuitive and incredibly hard to develop on it? What am I missing here? Even a silly thing like "Due date reminder" is so complicated on SharePoint. I have spent hours and hours to fix some really stupid issues. What am I missing here?

PS: First time on Stackoverflow and guys, your question posting tool is slick!! Loving the realtime preview.

Answer (score 0):

2: You cannot create a reasonably complicated SharePoint workflow using only SharePoint designer, you must have a visual studio development environment.

You absolutely must have a virtual machine with SharePoint installed for development. [It is completely straight forward to install everything](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb330848%28v=office.12%29.aspx#Office2007SystemSetUpDevEnv_SharePointProductsandTechnologiesDevelopment).

3: No two ways about it, SharePoint is a large and complicated system. I had similar issues while starting work with SharePoint and my experience was that my lack of understanding was leading me to try and shoehorn solutions that would not fit within the SharePoint architecture works. "Going against the grain" in this manner does create a lot of issues and is particularly difficult.

If it is possible, I would recommend searching for a local SharePoint user group and get in contact with the SharePoint experts there as space/time does not permit a full run down of SharePoints architecure and workflow.

P.s. Often, complicated workflow scenarios are easier with a third pary workflow solution such as [K2](http://www.k2.com) or [Nintex](http://www.nintex.com/en-US/Products/Pages/Workflow2007.aspx)